# Canonical representation of programs

Tags: algorithms, normal-forms

I'm working on some compiler software, and I'm looking for information on canonical forms for expressing software, algorithms, mathematical expressions (including predicate logic), etc. I assume canonicalization is generally intractable, but NP algorithms and more-constrained problems (e.g. pure functions) are also interesting. Normal forms may be useful too. My goal is not to be able to represent and manipulate all programs, but some of them (the trivial ones).

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you try explaining things a bit more?

Comment: The set of sequences of operations that express a given algorithm is infinite. I desire a representation that is (provably?) unique for every unique algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form In more practical terms, imagine if there were a programming language where every program you could write had one and exactly one way to be written in that language. Logical equivalence between two programs means equivalent source code. As I said, generally intractable, but not unapproachable.

Comment: This seems like a tall order...

Comment: I'm pretty certain that in the general case this is the halting problem. Canonical forms imply that there is a test for equivalence, and testing two programs for equivalence is unsolvable. But if Wolfram Alpha can do this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28cos+u%29%5E2-1%3D1-2%28sinu%29%5E2 then equivalence is *sometimes* testable. I'm probably wrong, but I feel like that implies that such things can be expressed uniquely.

Comment: With a finite number of operations, the set of possible programs in canonical form is finite. The only thing left for it to be denumerable is an ordering.

Comment: This question seems too broad.  Canonical forms for *what* particular problem?  If you're asking for an overview of canonical forms and normal forms across all of computer science, then that's too broad to work well on this site -- answers could be enormous.  The answer will depend on the set of programs/expressions/whatever that can be expressed in your particular language: for some sets, it is possible to find canonical forms; for others, we don't know how to do it efficiently; for yet others, it is undecidable.

Comment: So you want to transform a program such that it's easy to recognize that it's implementing eg bubble sort?

Comment: I have no particular problem in mind. I'm not an academic so I don't have access to journals. I'm just looking for a launching point.

Comment: @adrianN That's what I want, but that's *not* what I expect.

Comment: Actually, bubble sort is semantically equivalent to any other sorting algorithm. I suppose I haven't defined "unique" algorithm well.

Comment: Do you have any use cases in mind? What, in the compiler software, do you need this for? Which kinds of programs are you looking for? For apps that do (ostensibly) simple things, like propagate data from a server to a user, or for more mathematics / computer science jobs?

Comment: The use case is to combine compiler optimization with computer algebra and solving. The language is a hybrid 5th geneneration. https://sites.google.com/site/plangelanguage/home

Comment: @Brent the closest thing I know is automatic invariant generation in the context of verification. I think it's too weak to recognize sorting though. Here are some slides about it [1](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/conferences/vtsa14/slides/kovacs1.pdf), [2](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/conferences/vtsa14/slides/kovacs2.pdf), [3](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/conferences/vtsa14/slides/kovacs3.pdf), [4](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/rg1/conferences/vtsa14/slides/kovacs4.pdf)

Comment: I agree that the question is not answerable in its current form. You need to say at least of what you want normal forms, and what you want to be able to do with them.

Comment: You should treat programs formally, the same as with formal polynomials.  That is as opposed to two polynomials being equivalent if and only if they're the same function.  With formal equivalence they're equal if and only if the polynomial coefficients are equal.  In the program case that would mean they're equal if and only if - well the only simple way is string equivalence.  From that you take quotients to introduce commuting statements and so on.  Both formal and functional equivalence are considered (for polynomials) thruout mathematics, but by default Algebra considers things formally.

Answer (score 1):

The brief survey [contained in this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2609842) might be of interest:

J. Swan, Z. A. Kocsis, and A. Lisitsa. 2014. The 'representative' metaheuristic design pattern. In Proceedings of the Companion Publication of the 2014 Annual Conference on Genetic and Evolutionary Computation (GECCO Comp '14). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 1435-1436. DOI=http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2598394.2609842.

It discusses the existence of canonical forms for various forms of representation (groups, rings, boolean functions etc) and in particular normal forms for the lambda calculus using $\beta$-reduction as a rewrite rule.

Comment: No pay wall: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~jsw/metaheuristic-design-patterns/representative.pdf

Answer (score -3):

this general area fits into the concept/ subarea of [intermediate representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_language)/ IRs. here are some basic overviews/ surveys/ refs to start. another related area with large theory is [bytecodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode). there is some analysis of "canonicalization" of IRs but it is possibly or probably not a major focus in compiler design because, as you say, its undecidable in general. the more practical/ common approach is apparently a "normalizing" or "best-attempt/ heuristic streamlining" of the IRs. a technique that has seen major applied advancement in recent times is [just-in-time compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) eg in Java [hotspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot)/ Javascript ([v8 engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine))).

- [The Challenge of Cross-language Interoperability: The increasing significance of intermediate representations in compilers](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2544374) / Chow
- [Lecture Notes on Intermediate Representation](http://symbolaris.com/course/Compilers12/10-irtrees.pdf) / Pfenning
- [NORMAL FORM FOR COMPILER TESTING](https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/hjs/pubs/compilers/normal-form.pdf) / Hanan Samet